# If statement for accelerometers in watchkit

Tags: xcode, swift3, watchkit, accelerometer

I'm trying to create an app which performs an action after an apple watch is raised a certain height.

I have this code for a label

```
 self.labelX.setText(String(format: "%.2f", data!.acceleration.x))
```

which displays changing values from the accelerometer.

How do I perform an action using an if statement

For example: If labelX is greater than one?

Comment: please help me someone

Answer (score 0):

The accelerometer data won't really be of too much use to give you the height at which the watch was raised to.

Regardless, you can have an if statement that checks if the acceleration value is greater than a specified value and if so you can update your label or perform whatever else you need to do.

Comment: If accelerometer data wont be of much help, how else could I achieve this?